# Build ReactJS component where siblings components need to commuicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to figure out the best way to structure a particular type of ReactJS Element.

So lets say I have this element called ContentArea.  A ContentArea can be composed on a number of other custom elements, ContentAreaHeader, ContentAreaContent, and ContentAreaAction.  ContentArea, ContentAreaHeader, and ContentAreaContent are basically wrapper elements that wrap its child in the correct HTML element with the proper classes.  Implementation of ContentAreaAction is not important to this question, just wanted to mention it to show there are a number of different elements.  The ContentArea should only have 1 header element but should be able to support multiple other items (ContentAreaContent and/or ContentAreaAction).

One feature is being able to click on the header and toggle the display the other elements beside the header.  Coming from the AngularJS world, my initial though was to create a directive that I could just reuse so I tried that in ReactJS and my code looked this this:

```
var MyPage  = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ContentArea>
        <ContentAreaHeader>My Header</ContentAreaHeader>
        <ContentAreaContent className={cssClasses.join(' ')}>My Content</ContentAreaContent>
      </ContentArea>
    );
  }
});
```

Now I could add the event and collapsed state stuff this the MyPage component but then I can only have 1 ContentArea per page element or have multiple copied of that for each ContentArea, neither of which are good.  In AngularJS, each component can have its own scope and inherit from its parent which would prevent this issue.

My current solution is that I have created the following mixin:

```
var ContentAreaCollapsableMixin = {
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      collapsed: false
    };
  },

  toggleCollapse: function() {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    });
  }
}
```

Now to be able to have multiple ContentAreas per page elements, I create a custom ContentArea element for the needs of the page:

```
var MyContentArea  = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    contentArea.mixins.collapsable
  ],

  render: function() {
    var cssClasses = [];

    console.log(this.state.collapsed);

    if(this.state.collapsed) {
      cssClasses.push('u-hide');
    }

    return (
      <ContentArea>
        <span onClick={this.toggleCollapse}><ContentAreaHeader>My Header</ContentAreaHeader></span>
        <ContentAreaContent className={cssClasses.join(' ')}>My Content</ContentAreaContent>
      </ContentArea>
    );
  }
});

var MyContentArea2  = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    contentArea.mixins.collapsable
  ],

  render: function() {
    var cssClasses = [];

    if(this.state.collapsed) {
      cssClasses.push('u-hide');
    }

    return (
      <ContentArea>
        <span onClick={this.toggleCollapse}><ContentAreaHeader>My Header</ContentAreaHeader></span>
        <ContentAreaContent className={cssClasses.join(' ')}>My Content</ContentAreaContent>
        <ContentAreaContent className={cssClasses.join(' ')}>My Content2</ContentAreaContent>
      </ContentArea>
    );
  }
});

var ContentAreaComponents = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="test" className="test">Content Area</h1>
        <MyContentArea />
        <MyContentArea2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Note I am using the span to attach my event since as far as I know I can't attach event to custom/child elements and the header should not always have this event so I don't want to pollute the header directive with that content (and maybe I might want to add that event to an icon in the header instead of the whole header).

Is this the correct way to build this type of functionality when dealing with element that are wrappers and have an hierarchy like this?

Comment: “I can’t attach event to custom/child elements” Perhaps that’s true by default, but if your implementation of `ContentAreaHeader` had something like `return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>...</div>;`, the event handler would be threaded through properly with `<ContentAreaHeader onClick={this.toggleCollapse}>` and you wouldn’t need a wrapper `span`.

Comment: @icktoofay I understand that however The content of the header is not fixed and I may not always want the click event on the main header element (like I mention, maybe sometimes I want it on a svg element in the header element).

Comment: So then you propagate the `onClick` to something that’s not the element itself. E.g. the implementation of `ContentAreaHeader` would have `<div><span className="expand" onClick={this.props.onClick}>+</span> ...</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this is by passing components as props.  For example:

```js
<ContentArea
  header={"My Header"}
  content={[
    <div>My Content</div>,
    <div>My Other Content</div>
  ]}
  />
```

This looks a bit odd in JSX, so you can do it without if you prefer.

```
React.createElement(ContentArea, {
  header: "My Header",
  content: [
    <div>My Content</div>,
    <div>My Other Content</div>
  ]
})
```

In ContentArea you can simply render these props as you'd render props.children, but with more control.

```actionscript
var ContentArea = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){ return {open: true} },
  toggleOpen: function(){ this.setState({open: !this.state.open}) },

  render: function(){
    var className = this.state.open ? "" : "hidden";

    return (
      <div>
        <ContentAreaHeader onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
          {this.props.header}
        </ContentAreaHeader>

        {this.props.content.map(function(element, index){

          return (
            <ContentAreaContent className={className} key={index}>
              {element}
            </ContentAreaContent>
          );

        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The resulting structure in this example would be:

```xml
<ContentArea>
  <div>
    <ContentAreaHeader>My Header</ContentAreaHeader>
    <ContentAreaContent className="..." key="0">
      <div>My Content</div>
    </ContentAreaContent>

    <ContentAreaContent className="..." key="1">
      <div>My Other Content</div>
    </ContentAreaContent>
  </div>
</ContentArea>
```

---

This is the way that doesn't break any rules.  The way to do it with the API you mentioned is with [React.Children.map](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) and determining if it's a header or content based on the index (e.g. 0 is the header, and 1..infinity are content), and you wrap it in a div to apply the click handler and className respectivley.

Comment: 2 things, your solution does not allow for me to determine if the content is a ContentAreaContent or a ContentAreaAction (an there might be type of content) and 2. you mentioned "This is the way that doesn't break any rules" but don't mention what rules I am breaking, I be interested in what rules my implement break.

Comment: For the first you can modify it to fit your needs, I don't entirely understand what you're doing.  For the breaking rule, I mean trying to look at the things in props.children and check what component they're an instance of, or other hacky things that aren't documented.